# find control in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="a" OnClick="a_Click" Text="apd"/>    
    </form>
</body>
```

Code

```
protected  void a_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(((Button)FindControl("a")).Text);

}
```

This code works fine.

However, this code:

HTML

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Student/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server"> 
</asp:Content> 
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="a" OnClick="a_Click" Text="andj"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Code

```
protected void a_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(((Button)FindControl("a")).Text);
}
```

This code does not work and `FindControl` returns `Null` - why is this?

The `FindControl` method works in a simple page fine, but in a master page, does it not work?

The ID of the `a` is changed to `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_a` - how can find control?

Comment: The clientID and the id is not the same, and clientidmode won't change anything in this example

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To find the button on your content page you have to search for the `ContentPlaceHolder1` control first.
Then use the `FindControl` function on the `ContentPlaceHolder1` control to search for your button:

```
 ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
 Response.Write(((Button)cph.FindControl("a")).Text);
```

Comment: Is this code placed in the code behind of the master or the page you are trying to locate controls on.  I think you mean the master but just for clarification.

Comment: @Chef_Code: Yes. The master.

Comment: However if you are in a control instead of the page, you can use the following code: `this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");`

Answer (score 4):

You may try this..

```
this.Master.FindControl("Content2").FindControl("a");
```

You may refer this article...

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to how ASP.NET names the client IDs for nested controls.  Look at the page source and see exactly what ASP.NET is naming your control.

For example, looking at my page I can see that the button within the content placeholder renders like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn1" value="hello" id="MainContent_btn1" />
```

In this case FindControl("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn1") returns a reference to the Button.

Comment: To expand on his last comment, using View Source on your web browser to see the full name that ASP.NET generates (it can be quite long).

Comment: 'a' changed to 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_a' now how can find control?

Comment: FindControl("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$a")

Comment: While this would work if he were using jQuery or JS on the client end, this is not the proper technique to find a control in the code behind. You need to find the content1 control first, then find the a control underneath it as stated in some answers below.

Answer (score 1):

if the page to look for has no master page

```
this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
```

else

```
this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("controlAFromPage");
```

Answer (score 0):

controls are nested. you have your page, inside the page there is more controls, some of these controls contain controls themselves. the FindControl method only searches the current naming container, or if you do Page.FindControls if will only look for the controls in Page, not in the Controls inside those controls so you must search recursively.

if you know the button is inside the content place holder and you know its id you can do:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
Response.Write(((Button)cph.FindControl("a")).Text);
```

alternatively, if your controls is deeply nested, you can create a recursive function to search for it:

```
private void DisplayButtonText(ControlCollection page)
{
   foreach (Control c in page)
   {
      if(((Button)c).ID == "a")
      {
         Response.Write(((Button)c).Text);
         return null;
      }
      if(c.HasControls())
      {
         DisplayButtonText(c.Controls);
      }
}
```

initially you would pass this Page.Controls

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
       Button img = (Button)cph.FindControl("btncreate_email");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should find any Control on page

```
private Control FindALL(ControlCollection page, string id)
{
  foreach (Control c in page)
  {
    if (c.ID == id)
    {
      return c;
    }

    if (c.HasControls())
    {
      var res = FindALL(c.Controls, id);

      if (res != null)
      {
        return res;
      }
    }     
  }
  return null;
}
```

Call like:

```
Button btn = (Button)FindALL(this.Page.Controls, "a");
btn.Text = "whatever";
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the master page control on the other pages we can use this:

```
Button btnphotograph = (Button)this.Master.FindControl("btnphotograph");
btnphotograph.Text="Hello!!";
```

Answer (score -3):

See if the ID of the control is in fact being rendered as 'a'.  Use firebug or developer tools while page is loading.  You can change client id mode to static and get the same ID each time.

Comment: 'a' changed to 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_a' now how can find control?

Comment: Well you can put that ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_a as the name it'd probably find it.  Or change the button to clientidmode = static and see what the id is then.  It should just stay 'a'.