# How to change asp button ID using C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a table dynamically using c# and I am adding buttons to each cells. I need to assign button IDs for each of them so I can identify them later. I used following code for that.

```
bt.ID = rowIndex + c.ToString();   //bt.ID = "newID";
```

But when I try to access this button later it gives me an error.

```
Button seatButton = (Button)this.FindControl("a1");
seatButton.BackColor = Color.Red;   //Gives an error here
seatButton.Enabled = false;         //Gives an error here
```

I think the problem is with changing the button ID. I need to know the reason of this error and the cure..

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830198/find-control-in-page , I think this will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here your `seatButton`  must be null from the statement:

```
Button seatButton = (Button)this.FindControl("a1");
```

Rather than just doing `this.FindControl` , you can look for the placeholder of your control first and then get the button control, or search recursively through all the page controls.

**Method I:** Using ContentPlaceHolder way.

```
ContentPlaceHolder contentPH = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MyContentPlaceHolder");
 Button seatButton = (Button)contentPH.FindControl("a1");
```

**Method II::** Search recursively through the page controls.

Call getControl method once from appropriate part of your code

```
GetControl(Page.Controls);
```

// and method looks like:

```
private void GetControl( ControlCollection controls )
{
  foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
{
     if(ctrl.ID == "a1")
    {
       seatButton = (Button)ctrl;
    }

     if( ctrl.Controls != null)
     // call recursively this method to search nested control for the button 
     GetControl(ctrl.Controls);    
}

}
```