# CheckBox ID is unable to be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check a checkbox after finding that it is checked in database. I'm trying this:

```
string chkboxbit = String.Empty;
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
chkboxbit = "ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1_chk" + item + "" + i;
cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl(chkboxbit.ToString());
cb.Checked = false;
```

But I'm getting cb value null on debugging.

Comment: You sure that control is in your page?

Comment: is value of chkboxbit correct after concatenating with item & i??

Comment: Please edit your post and add the HTML tag as well as the value of `chkboxbit` post concatenation.

Comment: I think you're going about finding your control the wrong way.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830198/find-control-in-page

Comment: Can you please share your html code or your .aspx page code?

Comment: Yes, i m sure that Control is in my page. Its Id is 'chkProject4' and while ruuning page, after inspecting element, id is same and name becomes ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1_chkProject4.  

Here is my aspx code :
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkProject4" CssClass="accesschkbox" runat="server"  ClientIDMode = "Static" onClick="CheckProject()" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it... and it works fine...

```
chkboxbit = "chk" + item + "" + i;
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
cb = ((CheckBox)cph.FindControl(chkboxbit));
if (cb != null)
    cb.Checked = false;
```

Thnks to all for their effort.
and Thanks Kyojimaru.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this:

```
chkboxbit = "ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1_chk" + item + "" + i;
```

It appears you are mistaking the ID in the HTML for the ID that you give in the `.ASPX` page.

`ct1000` usually come from the master page. I would bet you only need to do this:

```
chkboxbit = "ContentPlaceHolder1_chk" + item + i.ToString();
```

And your control should be found.

Comment: Hey Adama, it is still not working.
while ruuning page, after inspecting element, id is same and name becomes ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1_chkProject4. Here is my aspx code : <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProject4" CssClass="accesschkbox" runat="server" ClientIDMode = "Static"