# Reference specific asp.net control using vb.net code bhind variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have read through many different solutions both here on SO and other sites but this keeps eluding me.

I am trying to reference an asp.net textbox and image button from code behind vb.net.

I have tried this code but the variable tBox says it equal is nothing.

```
Dim callBtn As ImageButton = CType(sender, ImageButton)
Dim tBox As TextBox
Dim iButton As ImageButton
Dim cNumber As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(callBtn.ID.Substring(11))
tBox = CType(Page.FindControl("TextBox" & cNumber), TextBox)
'The line below is commented out because it did not work either but
was the first one I tried
'tBox = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("TextBox" & cNumber), TextBox)
tBox.Text = "" <--- On this line tBox is nothing
tBox.Visible = False
```

I have placed a break point on the tBox.Text line and tBox equals nothing.

How can I reference the text box from a variable? I also need to reference and image button as well but need to get this one to work first.

If there is a question on here that exactly answers this please point me to it as I could not find one.

Edit: Update
Here is the code that creates a textbox and image button.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="removeFile" ImageUrl="~/Images/red-x-md20x20.png" ImageAlign="Top" ToolTip="Click To Remove File" />&ensp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="300px" />
```

Comment: Is `cNumber` definitely 1? Are these controls nested in some way? If so then have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830198/find-control-in-page)

Comment: No cNumber is not define as 1. It could range from 1 to 20. It is defined by the calling button which is ImageButton# where # can be from 1 to 20. No they are not nested. Each set of textbox and imagebutton are in one row of an asp.net table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was not looking for the right Name. Being on a content page I had to reference the master page first.

I used the following:

```
Dim ctrlNameT As String = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderRight$TextBox" & cNumber
```

This did the trick!