# c# equivalent to document.getElementById("ListBox"+i+"Item"+j).selected=true

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I've created a dynamic webpage using strictly html, javascript, and MS Access.  While it was functional, locally, there were complications deploying it.  Since I have ported the data to MySQL and am trying to use Visual Studio's aspx.cs to do much of what the javascript did previously.

I have a screen that populates a dynamic set of rows based on a query result (two rows per record for aesthetics), one of the cells contains a drop down menu(html select/ asp:ListBox).

When I had everything only on javascript, I could create the cell, then create its contents, then set the selected value using:

```
 document.getElementById("StatusDD" + rowCount).value = reader.GetValue(i);
```

From what I've gathered so far, the rough equivalent is:

```
 ListItem li = StatusDD1.Items.FindByValue(reader.GetValue(i));
 li.Selected = true;
```

However, I cannot simply hardcode StatusDD1 thru StatusDDx (for one, at the beginning my hardcoded set might be larger than the number of records returned, and two eventually the rows returned will be larger than the set of hardcoded values).

So what I did was I created the following function:

```
 protected void setSelected(string selectId, string value)
     {
         /*Need to put something here to make the following work*/
         selectId.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
     }
```

The selectId being passed in is the name/id of the ListBox and the value is the value coming back from the query.
It's called like:

```
 setSelected("StatusDD" + rowCount, (string)reader.GetValue(i));
```

If I could, for lack of better phrase, materialize the name created by "StatusDD"+rowCount, I could pass that name in as if I was passing in a ListBox, rather than a string.

Alternatively, if there was a way to select the ListBox from an array where I could do a conditional check WHERE/IF ListBox.Name = selectId, something like the following **PseudoCode**:

```
 ListBox a = ListBox.NameMatches(selectId);
 a.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

Currently ListBoxes are being created by defining the box in a string and then passing that string into an HtmlTableCell:

```
     HtmlTable myTable = new HtmlTable();
     HtmlTableRow newRow;
     string cellId;
     string cellContents;
     int rowCount = 1;
     string statusDisabled = "";

     while (reader.Read()){
        newRow = new HtmlTableRow();
        myTable.Rows.Add( newRow );
        ...
        ...
        cellContents = "<asp:ListBox name='StatusDD" + rowCount + "' id='StatusDD" + rowCount + "' style='width:100%; " + statusDisabled + "' value='" + reader.GetValue(i) + "' onchange='markNeedSave(" + (rowCount + 1) + ")'><asp:ListItem value='0'></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem value='1'>New</asp:ListItem>....asp:ListBox>";

        newRow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell{InnerHtml = cellContents});
     }
```

If it helps, here's how I had it working in javascript:

```
     while (!rs.EOF) {
        rowa = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        rowa.id = "RECORD" + rowCount + "a";
        cell = rowa.insertCell(i + 1);
        cell.id = "RECORD" + rowCount + "_CELL" + (i + 1);

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
           cell.innerHTML = "<select name='StatusDD" + rowCount + "' id='StatusDD" + rowCount + "' style='width:100%' value='" + rs.fields(i).value + "' onchange='markNeedSave(" + (rowCount + 1) + ")'><option value='NONE'></option><option value='New'>New</option>...</select>";
           if (readonly) {
               document.getElementById("StatusDD" + rowCount).disabled = true;
           }
           document.getElementById("StatusDD" + rowCount).value = rs.fields(i).value;
        }
     ...
     }
```

***OK, got the ListBox to work, but as I was researching, and when I finally got it to work, I discovered that what I wanted was the DropDownList, not the ListBox, but the same fixes needed to be done in order to get either to work.***

**I use the following function now:**

```
    protected void setSelected(string selectId, string value)
    {
       PlaceHolder TCS = Page.FindControl("TestingCS") as PlaceHolder;
       DropDownList ddl = TCS.FindControl(selectId) as DropDownList;
           if (ddl != null)
           {
                ddl.SelectedValue = value;
                ListItem item = ddl.Items.FindByValue(value);
                if(item != null)
                {    item.Selected = true;}
           }
    }
```

Also, for my cell contents that just contain data using the following is fine:

```
    cellContents = "<someString>";
    newRow.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell{InnerHtml = cellContents});
```

but for my drop down (or list box) I need to use:

```
    cell = new HtmlTableCell();
    newRow.Cells.Add(cell);
    DropList = new DropDownList();
    DropList.ID = "StatusDD" + rowCount;
    DropList.Items.Add(new ListItem("", "0"));
    DropList.Items.Add(new ListItem("New", "1"));
    ...

    cell.Controls.Add(DropList);
    setSelected(DropList.ID, (string)(reader.GetValue(i)));
```

**A smoother solution:**

```
    protected void setSelected(DropDownList ddl, string value)
    {
        ListItem item = ddl.Items.FindByValue(value);
        if (item != null)
        { item.Selected = true; }
    }
```

...

```
    protected void accessRecord()
    {
        ...
        DropList = new DropDownList();
        DropList.ID = "StatusDD" + rowCount;
        DropList.Attributes["onChange"] = "javascript:markNeedSave(" + rowCount + ");";
        DropList.Items.Add(new ListItem("", "0"));
        DropList.Items.Add(new ListItem("New", "1"));
        ...
        cell.Controls.Add(DropList);
        setSelected(DropList,(string)reader.GetValue(i));
    }
    ...
```

Comment: How are you creating your list boxes? Is this WebForms?

Comment: For your first question, I've add that to the tail end of the question above.
For the second,  yes: ASP.NET Web Forms Site.

Comment: Have you tested the output of this approach? Adding server controls as strings won't render them as you expect. I would recommend instead instantiating and then populating a ListBox and adding it to the HtmlTableCell's `Controls` property, as well as to a `Dictionary<string,ListBox>` field that you could then retrieve that listbox from by whatever ID you give it as a key.

Comment: Something like:

        `Dictionary<string,ListBox> ListBoxList = new Dictionary<string,ListBox>();
        ...
        ListBoxList.Add("StatusDD" + rowCount,new ListBox());`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the function you're looking for is [FindControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2). This can be used from the `Page`, or any parent control you might have created to hold your output.

An example implementation of your `setSelected` method might look like this:

```
 protected void SetSelected(string selectId, string value)
 {
     var lb = Page.FindControl(selectId) as ListBox;
     if (lb != null)
     {
         var item = lb.Items.FindByValue(value)
         if(item != null)
             item.Selected = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: So far the concept seems to work, however I am running into a few issues that I think have to do with the order of population.  

lb is null for every iteration, and I think that is because the table and its contents aren't yet written to the page for the controls to find them.  However, if I populate the table before creating the rows, then the table gets created and populated, but the rows are not populated, and thus the same null issue.  Once I have worked through that, I believe I will be able to confirm this is the answer I need.

Comment: Are you making sure to set the ID property for each list box you create?

Comment: Here the result when I inspect the element:`<asp:ListBox name="StatusDD1" id="StatusDD1" style="width:100%; disabled=''" value=2 onchange="markNeedSave(2)" SelectionMode="Single"><asp:ListItem value=0></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem value=1>New</asp:ListItem>`

During debugging lb is still returning null.

Comment: @wolfsshield Have you added the control to the page before running SetSelected? Are you still trying to add the ListBox's as `InnerHtml` or have you moved to creating controls and added them?

Comment: Going to try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830488/11035837

A little bit of both, still transitioning to creating controls

Comment: See the edit in the question.  You provided the key to what I as trying to do, but there were a few other gaps in my knowledge that you helped clarify as well, before I could get it to work.  Thank-you!

Comment: I have since found a smoother way to handle this....shown in the edit above